# Application built using Next.js and @mui, The @Mui default css isnt appearing Which breaks the site

Tags: typescript, next.js, material-ui

THe css of @mui never works, I have seen some solutions here but none seems to work for me.
THis is the App
https://myfreecourse-front-v2-r0rfrryqq-hamza172.vercel.app

Using @mui v5
Next.js 13
with Typescript

my _document file is

```
import React from 'react';
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript, DocumentContext } from 'next/document';
import { ServerStyleSheets } from '@mui/styles'; 

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx: DocumentContext) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    return { ...initialProps };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

// `getInitialProps` belongs to `_document` (instead of `_app`),
// it's compatible with server-side generation (SSG).
MyDocument.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  // Resolution order
  //
  // On the server:
  // 1. app.getInitialProps
  // 2. page.getInitialProps
  // 3. document.getInitialProps
  // 4. app.render
  // 5. page.render
  // 6. document.render
  //
  // On the server with error:
  // 1. document.getInitialProps
  // 2. app.render
  // 3. page.render
  // 4. document.render
  //
  // On the client
  // 1. app.getInitialProps
  // 2. page.getInitialProps
  // 3. app.render
  // 4. page.render

  // Render app and page and get the context of the page with collected side effects.
  const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

  ctx.renderPage = () => originalRenderPage({
    enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />),
  });

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

  return {
    ...initialProps,
    // Styles fragment is rendered after the app and page rendering finish.
    styles: [...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles), sheets.getStyleElement()],
  };
};
```

My _App file is

```
import '@/styles/globals.css'
import '@/styles/universal.css'
import '@mui/material/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import ScopedCssBaseline from '@mui/material/ScopedCssBaseline';
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'


export default function App({ Component,pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <ScopedCssBaseline>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ScopedCssBaseline>
    </>
  );
}
```

I have tried adding getInitialProps in _Document file.
Adding ScopedCssBaseline and CssBaseline in _app File, that didnt work as well.